# Why having $ma+np=1$ implies that $m$ is the inverse?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading Stilwell's: *Elements of Number Theory*. In here:

> [image]

I don't understand why having $ma+np=1$ implies that $m$ is the inverse.

Comment: We have $ma\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, since $p$ divides $ma-1$ (for note that $ma-1=-np$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $[ma+np]=[m][a]+[n][p]$ and $[p]=[0]$ then $[m][a]=[1]$

Comment: What do you mean with $[]$?

Comment: $[a]=\{x\in{\Bbb Z}\ :\  x\equiv a\mod p\}$, the equivalence class of $a$.

Answer (score 4):

The statement "$x\equiv y \mod z$" means that $x$ differs from $y$ by a multiple of $z$ (everything is an integer here).

So in your case, if $ma+np=1$, then rewrite it as $ma-1=(-n)p$. This shows that $ma$ and $1$ differ by a multiple of $p$--which is what we said it means to have $ma\equiv 1\mod p$.

And your definition of inverses is just that.

Comment: Yes. Every multiple of $mp$ of $p$ puts $mp$ in the same class of equivalence, namely $mp=\overline{0}$, then $ma+\overline{0}=1$. I guess I get it now.